# Batch File Running but not Following All Steps/Apps Script also hit and miss

Tags: csv, batch-file, google-apps-script, google-sheets, batch-rename

**Task:** Move and rename .csv reports from a shared server folder to my Google Drive. At this point my apps script will take over and import into a specified Sheet. The apps scripts are embedded into each sheet (7 sheets total) but they are all the exact same code (changed for the specific files and sheets).

**Issue 1:** The batch script works every time flawlessly when run manually, but when scheduled, sometimes it will not rename my files (but will still move them).

**Issue 2:** The apps script is hit and miss, sometimes it runs perfectly and sometimes it fails with an error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearContents' of null".

Thus the Sheet is not updated and I have csv files sitting in my drive doing nothing.

**Batch Script**

```
@echo off
ren "\\Server\Folder\subfolder\DataDaily-Emb Smalls-*.csv" smalls.csv
ren "\\Server\Folder\subfolder\DataDaily-HP & Laser-*.csv" hp.csv
ren "\\Server\Folder\subfolder\DataDaily-Emb Hats-*.csv" hats.csv
ren "\\Server\Folder\subfolder\DataDaily-Embroidery-*.csv" emb.csv
ren "\\Server\Folder\subfolder\DataDaily-Screen Print-*.csv" sp.csv
ren "\\Server\Folder\subfolder\DataDaily-Database-*.csv" database.csv

robocopy \\Server\Folder\subfolder "G:\My Drive\Dashboard" /MOV /XF *.bat
```

**Apps Script Example** *hobbled together from different posts on this forum, it works on every other sheet except for this one*

```
function RecImport() {
  
  const csvFolderName = 'FolderName';
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("rec.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("rec");
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  DriveApp.getFilesByName("rec.csv").next().setTrashed(true);
}
```

**Example of other sheet code that works consistently**

```
function ImportSmallsCSVfromDrive() {

  const csvFolderName = 'FolderName';
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("smalls.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('smalls');
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  DriveApp.getFilesByName("smalls.csv").next().setTrashed(true);
}
```

Ultimately, I am at a loss here as everything looks like it should be working but yet I still have renaming inconsistencies with my batch script and failed executions on my apps script. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

File locks are often problems when you're changing a file on a schedule.  You can prove this by copying the files before the scheduled rename.  Copying will often succeed while files are locked and then changes can be made.

This may not fit your business case (maybe you can't copy them first) but it will help you identify the problem.

You can add this to your robocopy to log while scheduled.  You should get a detailed error message for the failed files.

```
>> c:\log.txt
```